# Codeigniter Pass Selected Value of dropdown in href

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the selected value of the dropdown. I have to pass that value in href as a 4th segment. I am not using the form and no submit too. In my View I have:

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($estimates);$i++) { ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span><?php echo $estimates[$i]->id_job; ?></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span><?php echo $estimates[$i]->date_of_plans; ?></span>
    </td>

    <td>
        <span><?php echo $estimates[$i]->business_name; ?></span>
    </td>

    <td>
        <span><?php echo $estimates[$i]->job_title; ?></span>
    </td>

    <td>
        <span><?php echo $estimates[$i]->date_estimated_needed; ?></span>
    </td>   
    <td>
        <span>JC</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="status" name="status">
            <option value="IN PROGRESS">IN PROGRESS</option>
            <option value="NOT STARTED">NOT STARTED</option>
            <option value="AWAITING CLIENT">AWAITING CLIENT</option>
            <option value="COMPLETE - QC">COMPLETE - QC</option>
            <option value="COMPLETE">COMPLETE</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td style='border:0px none;'>
    <a id="test" href="<?php echo site_url('frontpage/adminestimates')."/".$estimates[$i]->id_job ?>" class='btn btn-success' style='padding-left:24px; padding-right:24px; padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px;border-radius:4px;'>EDIT</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
     $("#test").live("click", function(){    
             $("#result").load($(this).attr("href"));        //result is the div where I have to load the new page. (as im using tabs so have to show page in div.
        return false;
     });
</script>
```

Controller.php

uri->segment(3) echo's the job id of the job which is edited. How to get the uri->segment(4) it :( because I have to pass this value to the model and then save it to the database to show the status of the job to the client.

```
public function adminestimates()
{
    echo $this->uri->segment(3); 
//echo $this->uri->segment(4); 
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `uri->segment(4)`  supposed to be?

Comment: The value selected in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$("#result").load($(this).attr("href")+"/"+$("#status").val());
```

Now you will get 4th segment in url.

You are creating status dropdown with same id and name inside a for loop. So, there is possibilities of duplicate in id and name. So change your dropdown id and name to be unique.

In your view file, change select as below:

```
<select id="status_<?php echo $estimates[$i]->id_job;?>" name="status_<?php echo $estimates[$i]->id_job;?>">
            <option value="IN PROGRESS">IN PROGRESS</option>
            <option value="NOT STARTED">NOT STARTED</option>
            <option value="AWAITING CLIENT">AWAITING CLIENT</option>
            <option value="COMPLETE - QC">COMPLETE - QC</option>
            <option value="COMPLETE">COMPLETE</option>
</select>
```

then for `a` tag,

```
<td style='border:0px none;'>
    <a id="<?php echo $estimates[$i]->id_job;?>" href="<?php echo site_url('frontpage/adminestimates')."/".$estimates[$i]->id_job ?>" class='btn btn-success' style='padding-left:24px; padding-right:24px; padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px;border-radius:4px;'>EDIT</a>
    </td>
```

In js code:

```
<script>
     $("a.btn-success").live("click", function(){  
          var id = $(this).attr("id");  
          $("#result").load($(this).attr("href")+"/"+$("#status_"+id).val());        //result is the div where I have to load the new page. (as im using tabs so have to show page in div.
        return false;
     });
</script>
```

Comment: I have to ask one thing more:

<select id="status" name="jobstatus">
<option value="IP">IN PROGRESS</option>
<option value="NS">NOT STARTED</option>
<option value="AC">AWAITING CLIENT</option>
<option value="CQ">COMPLETE - QC</option>
<option value="C">COMPLETE</option>
</select>

Whatever i select in the dropdown the 4th parameter goes as IP (In Progress) :( I have changed the name of the id and name in select tag.

Comment: what is the `IP`? Is it third parameter? check your html source. I think still you have naming / ID problem issue. each dropdon must have different id.

Comment: IP is the value of option like IN PROGRESS.  NS "NOT STARTED"...
Actually there are right now ten job records coming from the databse, so there are 10 rows of table and each row has the dropdown. The fourth parameters passes correct only for the first dropdown :(
If i change for e.g third dropdown to "Awaiting Client" then AC should pass as the fourth parameter but IP "IN PROGRESS" passes.. I dont know why it is happening so??

Comment: did you check dropdown name and id in html source? let me update the answer to fix the naming issues

Comment: Thanx its working perfectly :)
One more question Now I want that next time when the admin checks the job estimates. The selected dropdown value should be the one which is entered in the DB. I mean if the admin has changed the job status of job id 1 to COMPLETE from the IN PROGRESS then next time the dropdown of job status of job id 1 should be complete.
`code` <?php echo $estimates[$i]->job_status ?> gets the values of the job status from the db perfectly but don't know how to show it in the dropdown as a selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [jquery each function](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

if you put a listener on the element then you can pull its data